# uniformly continuous function is closed and bounded space

Tags: calculus, functions, vector-spaces, continuity, uniform-continuity

> **Important Note** (before closing this as duplicate):
>
> I saw multiple solutions to this problem but all of them using balls
>   which I don't want.

I need to prove that:

> If $f : D \to \Bbb R$ is a continuous mapping and 
>   $D$ is a compact subset of $\Bbb R^2$, then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $D$.

**What do I know?**

For all $\epsilon>0$ and all $P_0$ in $D$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that for every $P$ in $C$ the relation $d(P,P_0)<\delta$ implies $d(f(P),f(P_0))<\epsilon$.

The set $D$ is closed and bounded.

**What do I need to prove?**

For all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that for all $P,P_0$ in $D$ the relation $d(P,P_0)<\delta$ implies $d(f(P),f(P_0))<\epsilon$.

Comment: There was some discussion on the [now-deleted original version of this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3706262/proving-that-a-continuous-mapping-is-uniformly-continuous)

Comment: page not found...